# Which scripture tells about Saraswati upasana?

Tags: scripture, saraswati, upasana

Which scripture tells us about the rules and procedures for doing Saraswati upasana?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Hinduism Devi Saraswati is goddess of speech , learning ,music ,art.  She is depected as  sitting  on a white swan and holding a Vina  (stringed instrument) in her hands. She clad in white clothes and a book in her other hand , which are Vedas.  According to Pancharatra texts  she is one of the twenty-four emanations of Lakshmi accompanying Narayana. i.e. She is conceived as  Shakti related to Vishnu.

---

The method of worship of Devi Saraswati is described  in detail  in [**Devi-Bhagavata Purana**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57317.html) - Book 9 - Chapter 4 - **On the hymn, worship and Kavaca of Sarasvatī Devī**. This mode of worship of devi Saraswati is told by Narayana to Narada.

> 32-59. Nārāyaṇa said :-- O Nārada! I am now stating the method of
>   worship of the Devī Sarasvatī, the Mother of the Worlds, according to
>   Kaṇva Śākhā of the Yajurveda. Hear. On the day previous to the fifth
>   day of the bright fortnight of the month of Māgh or the day of
>   commencement of education, the devotee should control his senses,
>   concentrate his mind and take his bath. Then he is to perform his
>   daily duties and install the jar (Ghaṭa) with devotion and according
>   to the Mantras of the Kaṇva Śākhā or the Tantra, as the case may be.
>   He is to worship first on that Ghata (jar) Gaṇapati (Ganeśa), then
>   meditate the Devī Sarasvatī as described below, invoke Her and again
>   read the Dhyān and then **worship with Soḍaśopacāra (sixteen good
>   articles offered in the worship).** O Good One! Now I am speaking,
>   according to my knowledge, about the offerings as ordained in the
>   Vedas or Tantras. Hear. Fresh butter, curd, thickened milk, rice freed
>   from the husk by frying, sweetmeats (Til Laddu) prepared of Til, sugar
>   cane, sugarcane juice, nice Guḍ (molasses), honey, svastik, sugar,
>   rice (not broken) out of white Dhān, cipiṭak of table rice (Ālo cāl),
>   white Modak, Harbiṣyānna prepared of boiled rice with clarified butter
>   and salt, Piṣṭaka of jaoā or wheaten flour, Paramānna with ghee,
>   nectar like sweetmeats, cocoanut, cocoanut water, Svastik Piṣṭaka,
>   Svastik and ripe plantain Piṣṭaka, Kaseru (root), Mūlā, ginger, ripe
>   plantains, excellent Bel fruit, the jujube fruit, and other
>   appropriate white purified fruits of the season and peculiar to the
>   place are to be offered in the Poojā. O Nārada! White flowers of  good
>   scent, white sandalpaste of good scent, new white clothes, nice
>   conchshell, nice garlands of white flowers, nice white necklaces, and
>   beautiful ornament are to be given to the Devī. I say now the Dhyānam
>   sweet to hear, of the Devī Sarasvatī according to the Vedas, capable
>   to remove errors! Hear. I hereby bow down to the Devī Sarasvatī, of a
>   white colour, of a smiling countenance and exceedingly beautiful, the
>   lustre of whose body overpowers that of the ten millions of Moons,
>   whose garment is purified by fire, in whose hands there are Vīṇā and
>   books, who is decorated with new excellent ornaments of jewels and
>   pearls and whom Brahmā, Viṣṇu, Maheśvara and the other Devas, Munis,
>   Manus and men constantly worship. Thus meditating the Devī, the
>   intelligent persons should offer all articles, after pronouncing the
>   root Mantra. Then he is to hymn and hold Kavaca and make Sāṣṭāṅga
>   praṇāms before the Devī. O Muni! Those whose Devī Sarasvatī is the
>   presiding Deity, are not to be spoken of at all (i.e., they will
>   naturally do all these things and with a greater fervour). Besides all
>   should worship the Devī Sarasvatī on the day of commencement of
>   education and every year on the Śūkla Pañcamī day of the month of
>   Māgh. The eight-lettered Mantra, as mentioned in the Vedas is the root
>   Mantra of Sarasvatī. (Aim Klīm Sarasvatyai namaḥ). Or the Mantra to
>   which each worshipper is initiated is his Mūlmantra (not Mantra). Or
>   uttering the Mantra “Śrīm Hrīm Sarasvatyai Svāhā” one is to offer
>   everything to the Devī Sarasvatī. This Mantra is the Kalpa Vrikṣa (i.
>   e., the tree which yields all desires). Nārāyaṇa, the ocean of mercy,
>   gave in ancient times, this very Mantra to Vālmikī in the holy land
>   Bhārata Varṣa on the banks of the Ganges; next Bhrīgu gave this Mantra
>   on the occasion of solar eclipse to Maharṣi Sukrācarya on the Puṣkara
>   Tīrtha; Mārīca gave to Brihaspati on a lunar eclipse; Brahmā gave to
>   Bhrīgu in the Vadarikā Āśrama; Jaratkarā gave to Āstika on the shore
>   of the Kṣiroda ocean; Bibhānḍaka gave this to the intelligent
>   Ṛṣyasriṅga on the Sumeru mountain, Śiva gave this to Kaṇāda and
>   Gotama, Sūrya gave to Yājñavalkya and Kātyāyana, Ananta Deva gave to
>   Pāṇini, to the intelligent Bhāradvāja and to Śākaṭāyana in Bali’s
>   assembly in the Pātāla. If this Mantra be repeated four lakhs of
>   times, all men attain success. And when they become Siddhas with this
>   Mantra, they become powerful like Brihaspati.

---

In brief - The worship of Devi Saraswati should be performed as mentioned in Vedas/Tantaras with Shodasha Upachara i.e.with sixteen good articles offered in the worship.

Some of the food iteams offered to goddess are Ghee , Curd ,seasom laddu , white Modak ,  cocoanut ,suger honey , Jaggery, bel fruit , various iteams of cook rice (Sweet , sour) . etc. as naivaidya .

For Pooja purpose white flowers , white clothes, white sandal paste ,scent , conchshell,  garland of white flowers and ornaments can be offered to please the Goddess.

Worshipper  should perform Dhyana (meditation ) of Saraswati and offere all the articles to her. He should utter the  eight letter Saraswati Mool Mantra  " “Śrīm Hrīm Sarasvatyai Svāhā”  and "Aim Klīm Sarasvatyai namaḥ " only if he is initiated by his guru.

---

As mentioned in Devi Bhgvata  Purana the goddess should be worshipped by  Shodashopachar Puja which includes.

1) Avahana -Calling for goddess to come to puja 2) Asana - Providing seat for the deity to sit. 3) Padya - washing feet of the goddess with water.

4 ) Arghya -Offering water to goddess 5) Achamana -  Providing water for the goddess for drinking 6) Abhisheka - for bathing purpose ,  Offer continuous water offerings to the deity.

7 ) Vastra  8) UpaVastra- Offering   a garment .9 )Aroma -Offering Chandana as perfume to Goddess.

10) Pushpa - Offering flowers and flowers to God. 11) Dhoop - Offering incense made by incense-natural aroma. 12) Deep - Offering a lamp to the goddess and incense to the taja part of the deity.

13) Naivaidya- Offering prepared food items as prescribed in pooja vidhi to goddes.14 )Pradakshina - completing  a circle around goddess idol. 15) Namaskar - Greetings to the Goddess.    16 ) Mantrapushpanjali-  Offering godliness and flowers to God as a symbol of anything short of mantra-worship.

So the above is the way one can perform an Upasana or Pooja of Devi Saraswat. Also we can sing Aarati  , can chants various  Devi Saraswati mantras etc. during the upasana puja and can meditate on her as a  supreme Goddess.